# Blocking main thread when calling one method while another one is running

Tags: c#, user-interface, .net-3.5, thread-safety

In my application there is a `ListView` with files and folders. User can load them on server. Loading is performing in separate thread but I show the state of the process in a progress bar on the Form, using `Control.Invoke(ShowProgressMethod...` method, so `ShowProgressMethod` is called on the Main thread.

Everything works fine, but when I try to do something else in the Main thread (for example delete one file), the UI is blocked. It is usually happend when process is refreshed in `ShowProgressMethod` and during this I called another method from the same thread.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add tags to indicate language and framework...

Comment: Need to see some code. Sounds like you're doing the "loading" inside the UI thread.

Comment: I can't show code now because i don't have reputation((( "loading" is not doing inside UI i'm sure in it. I'll post code later